# Why do we only include the pivot 1/2 of the time in Hoare's Quicksort?

Tags: sorting, quicksort

According to Wikipedia, Hoare's partition (partial code) looks like:

```
// Sorts a (portion of an) array, divides it into partitions, then sorts those
algorithm quicksort(A, lo, hi) is 
  if lo >= 0 && hi >= 0 && lo < hi then
    p := partition(A, lo, hi) 
    quicksort(A, lo, p) // Note: the pivot is now included
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
```

I was curious why the pivot is included in the lo...p call but not in the p + 1...hi call (whereas they are both excluded in Lomuto's partitioning).

Wikipedia wrote:

> With this formulation it is possible that one sub-range turns out to be the whole original range, which would prevent the algorithm from advancing. Hoare therefore stipulates that at the end, the sub-range containing the pivot element (which still is at its original position) can be decreased in size by excluding that pivot, after (if necessary) exchanging it with the sub-range element closest to the separation; thus, termination of quicksort is ensured.

Why are we allowed to *include* the pivot in the lo...p subrange, but not in the p + 1...hi subrange? By the same logic in the above Wikipedia page, if the lo...p subrange is exactly the original range, wouldn't we run into the same infinite recursion problems?

Answer (score 0):

The index `p` may not be the pivot index. Elements equal to the pivot or the pivot itself can end up anywhere during a partition step. After a partition step, elements <= pivot are to the left or at `p`, elements >= pivot are to the right of `p`. By allowing the pivot or elements equal to the pivot to be swapped, the inner loops do not need to do bounds checking. Another advantage of Hoare partition scheme is it becomes faster as the number of duplicates increases (despite often swapping equal elements), while Lomuto becomes slower, degrading to O(n^2) time complexity if all elements are equal.